# Vertical Aligned Text and Image in list

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment

Is there a way of vertical aligning text and an image in a list?

e.g.

```
<li>Some text here <img src="image.jpg" alt="" /></li>
```

The text doesn't align in the middle of the side of the image, it appears at the bottom then the image is next to it. I need the text to be in the center point between the image on the side.

What's the best way of doing it? I know having a image inside a list isn't valid HTML (AFAIK).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
li img {vertical-align: middle;}
```

if text fits one line

Answer (score 1):

If the text doesn't wrap, you can set line-height same as the height of image:

```
li { line-height: 42px }
```

And yes, having `img` inside `li` is perfectly valid, since `img` is (by default) inline element while `li` is block level element.